# Issue with posting new text on typo3 site

Tags: sql, database, phpmyadmin, typo3, mariadb

on typo3 site colibri.hr when I add new page and then try to add some text to it shows that erorr..also when I click on disable text editor same thing, and on all other pages it allow me to change things but when I add new page to site and try to do smt not..

[image: PICTURE OF ERROR]

Answer (score 0):

I suspect it breaks on the reserved word 'recursive', which version of mariadb are you using?

Comment: Version is 10.2.17

Comment: TYPO3 uses Doctrine, Doctrine currently does not support MariaDB 10.2.7+. Schema creation/update is triggering infinite schema diffs: https://github.com/doctrine/dbal/pull/2825

Comment: @BerndWilkeπφ shoud I change it or how?

Comment: Yes, you can use MariaDB 10.1.x but 10.2 is not supported (9LTS does support it!)

Comment: anyway using reserved words for fields always is a bad idea. Even if a fieldname becomes a reserved word in a later version of DB. reserved word: [MariaDB](https://mariadb.com/kb/en/library/reserved-words/) / [MySQL](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/keywords.html)

Comment: @RIVATI how to switch back to earlier version?

Comment: @Monika You have to ask your hosting provider this, or your system administrator

Comment: What word was right before "recursive"?  Can you add backtics around `recursive`?